# Hide specific QStandardItem in QStandarItemModel based on some property

Tags: qt

```
QStandardItemModel *dataModel=new QStandardItemModel(this);

QStandardItem *simpleItem=new QStandardItem("simple");

dataModel.appendRow(simpleItem);
QStandardItem *complexItem=new QStandardItem("complex");

dataModel.appendRow(complexItem):

QTreeView *simpleTreeView=new QTreeView();
simpleTree.setModel(dataModel);

QTreeView *complexTreeView=new QTreeView();
complexTreeView.setModel(dataModel);
```

now I want to show simpleItem in simpleTreeView and hide all complexItem inserted.
And hide all simpleItem in complexTreeView vice verse.

Any suggestion, Solution?

Comment: I also know the name of QSortFilterProxyModel. But how can I use?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [`QSortFilterProxyModel`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qsortfilterproxymodel.html) which is responsible for filtering out the specific items.